# how to check textarea is null or not in javafx

Tags: javafx, textarea

How to check `TEXTAREA` is `null or not`.

I tried the following ways :

1. TEXTAREA.getText().trim().length() == 0  //NullPointer Exception.
2. TEXTAREA.equals(null) //NullPointer exception

Thanks,

pavan

Comment: Is TEXTAREA a `reference` for the TextArea ?

Comment: i am having ref. as txtRemarks. i used in these way
1) txtRemarks.getText().trim().length() == 0 , i am getting nullpointerexception. 
2) txtRemarks.equals(null) -- nullpointer exception

Comment: Can you show us some code on how are you creating the txtRemarks ?

Comment: @FXML TextArea txtRemarks;

Comment: Most probably you have used `id` in your fxml, instead of `fx:id`

Comment: in controller file ref. is txtRemarks and in fxml file fx:id is txtRemark , that's why i got null pointer exception. I Solved it by changing fx:id name.

Comment: Please try again, the problem must have been resolved. Both the issues were inter-related !